# Camera permission on iOS pwa

Tags: ios, permissions, camera, progressive-web-apps

iOS asks for camera permission on every page load.
Is there anyway to make it ask once when the pwa or webpage load for the first time?
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?